# not support object of Toolbar in setSupportActionBar method in android studio

Tags: java, android

I want to Add Toolbar but it not support object of Toolbar in setSupportActionBar method as I implement in android studio. so please any one tell me what is issue.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

app_bar.xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#DDD">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

styles.xml

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    </style>
```

dependencies

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Comment: Please post the error message

Answer (score 2):

You should extends

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

as  `ActionBarActivity`  deprecated

### Updated

Make a New **Theme** as below

```
 <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

and set it to

```
  <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
```

Comment: @M D I have implement AppCompatActivity bit not support object of toolbar.

Comment: @Alam Clean and Built your project properly.

Comment: @M D shows this error after clean and Built app incompatible types: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be converted to android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar

Comment: @Alam You should add `import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;` instead of `android.widget.Toolbar` in your `MainActivity`

Comment: @M D Thanks Bhaiya I got it by import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar